# Webpack logs on React compilation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, craco

The following logs are showing when I recompile a React app:

[image]

On previous projects, only the following would show:

[image: previous projects]

What could be causing this? Have I accidentally enabled a Webpack/Craco/TS setting?

Comment: can you share the package JSON files of two projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/

There are a ton of logging options you can use with devServer:

```
devServer:{
  quiet: false,
  noInfo: false,
  stats: {
      assets: false,
      children: false,
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false,
      colors: true,
      entrypoints: false,
      hash: false,
      modules: false,
      timings: false,
      version: false,
      builtAt: false,
      errors: false,
      errorDetails: false,
      errorStack: false,
      logging: false,
      // loggingDetails: true,
  }
```

}